# Eclipse and the generation of interface method stubs that contain generics information

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, eclipse-jdt

I am running into the following problem with Eclipse. An API I use makes use of generics in interfaces. Example:

```
interface X {
   ...
}
interface Y {
  List<? extends X> getObjects(int filter);
  ...
}
```

The javadoc for this API contains the information about those generics. The JAR obvisouly does not, because of the Java type erasure system.

When using auto-completion in Eclipse, I would expect it to pull this extra information out of the Java doc, and generate correct stubs such as:

```
class Foo implements Y {
  @Override
  public List<? extends X> getObjects(int filter) {
    return null;
  }
  ...
}
```

but it seems this does not happen... Eclipse generates the following:

```
class Foo implements Y {
  @Override
  public List getObjects(int filter) {
    return null;
  }
  ...
}
```

Notice that:

- the generics information on the return type is gone
- the correct parameter name is here, it was pulled from the javadoc properly

So that would mean that Eclipse uses the documentation only partially, to generate stubs with accurate parameter names, but does not use it to generate accurate prototypes. At least not on my system. I am using an up-to-date Luna with standard settings. Any idea if this is a bug or do I need to configure something? Thank you.

Comment: Generic type info is usually still saved in bytecode.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Autocomplete includes the type-parameters on my environment.

Comment: I too am running into the same issue @kocko is. The whole stub generates for me. Maybe try a fresh eclipse workspace? or even a fresh eclipse install?

Comment: You guys are right, type information should be saved as bytecode metadata. It turns out the library Jar was run through Proguard, which stripped out that piece of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Generics` are compile time typesafety in java (most of the time, this information is not available in class file.)

When you make an API (interface), you define (or) enforce a generic type T in your interface, and refer type T in all method signatures.

And when you create an actual concrete implementation of that interface, then you replace the Type T with your actual expected type class.

Since `interface Y` defined a concrete implementation instead of a generic type, that information will be removed after compilation so there is no way `Eclipse` to know that information.

For `Eclipse` to auto-generate with correct type, the API for `X` and `Y` should have been defined like:

```
interface X {  
 }

 interface Y<T extends X> {
   List<T> getObjects(int filter);
 }

class j implements X{   
}


class JJ implements Y<j>
{
    @Override
    public List<j> getObjects(int filter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```